# Adding a random column with years

Tags: python, dataframe

I am working with Python on a Pandas Dataframe which looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, I have successfully concatenated the Month and Day columns to get the "Monthdate" column. Now, as I am doing a time series analysis for practice, I would like to add a column for year in the dataframe. However, the data does not have year information, so , I would like to leave it to Python to randomize the years from 2019 - 2021.

Is there a way to do this or I am doomed because there is no data available?

Answer (score 1):

*-next time provide a code sample to work with, please-*

Concatenate your string with a random year chosen with random.randint

```
from random import randint
df['mdy'] = df.Monthdate.apply(lambda val: f'{val} {randint(2019,2022)}')
```

Comment: Thanks Anton Frolov for your answer. I will make sure that I include the code the next time.